# Remote users audio and video not displaying in Peerjs WebRTC

Tags: express, npm, webrtc, peerjs

I am pretty much new to PeerJs and WebRTC. Recently started to learn and develop and app for my school for remote classes due to Covid time.

When connection is established user who created can see him in video but remote persons audio/video doesn't show up.

Server code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('room-joined', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('new-user-connected', userId)

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
        })
        
        socket.on("offer", payload => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("offer-received", payload);
        });

        socket.on("answer", payload => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("answer-received", payload);
        });

        socket.on("ice-candidate", data => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("ice-candidate-message", data);
        });
    })
})
```

Client Code:

```
const socket = io('/');
var selectedCamera = 'user'
var totalUsers = []
let localStream;
let localId
let initiater;
let otherUserId;

const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/',
    port: '443',
    path: '/myapp',
    secure: true
});

peer.on("open", (id) => {
    localId = id;
    socket.emit("room-joined", roomId, id);
    totalUsers.push(id);
    initSelfStream();
    //console.log('My userId: ' + id)
});

const initSelfStream = () => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                {
                    video: {
                        facingMode: selectedCamera
                    },
                    audio: true
                }).then(stream => {
                    localStream = stream;
                    
                    const video = document.createElement("video");
                    loadAndShowVideoView(video, stream, localId);

                    socket.on('new-user-connected', id => {
                        setTimeout(function() { callUser(id, stream); }, 3000);
                        otherUserId = id;
                    });
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('(async () =>: ' + err);
        }
    })();
}

const callUser = (id, stream) => {
    test1 = createRtcPeerConnection(id);
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => test1.addTrack(track, localStream));
}

socket.on("offer-received", (data) => {
    if(data.target == localId){
        test1 = createRtcPeerConnection();
        const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
        test1.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(() => {
            localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => test1.addTrack(track, localStream));
        }).then(() => {
            return test1.createAnswer();
        }).then(answer => {
            return test1.setLocalDescription(answer);
        }).then(() => {
            const payload = {
                target: data.caller,
                caller: localId,
                sdp: test1.localDescription
            }
            socket.emit("answer", payload);
        });
    }
});
socket.on("answer-received", (data) => {
    if(data.target == localId){
        const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
        test1.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
});
socket.on("ice-candidate-message", (data) => {
    if(data.target == localId){
        if (data.candidate.candidate) {
            const payload = {
                target: otherUserId,
                candidate: data.candidate.candidate,
            }
            socket.emit("ice-candidate", payload);
        }
    }
});

const createRtcPeerConnection = (id) => {
    const rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
            {
                urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org"
            },
            {
                urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                credential: 'muazkh',
                username: 'webrtc@live.com'
            },
        ]
    });

    rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
    rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = handleTrackEvent;
    rtcPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = () => handleNegotiationNeededEvent(id);

    return rtcPeerConnection;
}

const handleICECandidateEvent = (e) => {
    if (e.candidate) {
        const payload = {
            target: otherUserId,
            candidate: e.candidate,
        }
        socket.emit("ice-candidate", payload);
    }
}
const handleTrackEvent = (e) => {
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    loadAndShowVideoView(video, e.streams[0], "Temporary Id")
}
const handleNegotiationNeededEvent = (targetUserID) => {
    test1.createOffer().then(offer => {
        return test1.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(() => {
        const payload = {
            target: targetUserID,
            caller: localId,
            sdp: test1.localDescription
        };
        socket.emit("offer", payload);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

const loadAndShowVideoView = (video, stream, id) => {
    video.classList.add('video-inset', 'background-black');
    video.setAttribute("id", id);
    video.style.position = "relative"
    video.autoplay = true;
    
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.style.height = 50+"vh"
    video.style.width = 50+"vw"
    
    video.muted = true;
    video.style.objectFit = "cover"
    
    appendVideo(video, stream, id)
}
const appendVideo = (video, stream, id) => {
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
            loader.style.opacity = 0
            container.append(video);
            video.play()
            if(loader.style.visibility == "visible") {
                loader.style.display = "none";
            }
    });
}
```

ejs view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
    const roomId = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <script src="peer.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="client.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container background-black" id="loader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-container background-black" id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking for some help

Answer (score 0):

ok im not a pro , but i've done my first webrtc project a while ago

first of all you should check your browser console for errors

second you seem to be using peerjs at some parts and using pure WEBRTC at some other parts ! i dont think that's going to work  .....  you need to choose one

you need `peer.on('call')` to listen to other user connection `call.answer(stream)` to send your stream for the caller and  `call.on('stream')` to receive the caller stream

it goes something like this

```
var peer = new Peer({
    config: {'iceServers': [
            { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        ]} /* Sample servers, please use appropriate ones */
});


peer.on('open', function(id) {
    MY_PEER_ID = id ;
    io.emit('peer_id_offer' , {  chat_room  : ROOM , id : id}); // send your peerid to other users in the room via socket.io 
});



// call other peers when you receive their id 
io.on('peer_id_recived' , function(data){
     callPeer(value.peer_id); // look at the function below 
});

// calling other peer when we receive their id via socket.io sending them our stream and expecting to receive theirs 
 function callPeer( id )
{
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video : true , audio : true })
        .then(  (stream) => {

            addOurVideo(stream);
            
            let  call = peer.call(id , stream);
            
            call.on('stream' , function(remoteStream){
                    addRemoteVideo(remoteStream);

            })
        })
        .catch( (e)=>{
            console.log('error1' , e );
        });
}




// handle reciving call from other clients in the room 
peer.on('call' , function (call) {


    /// send your own stream for the caller and add the caller stream to your page 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video : true , audio : true })
        .then((stream) => {
            
            call.answer(stream);
            call.on('stream' , function(remoteStream){
                
                    addRemoteVideo(remoteStream);
            })

        })
        .catch( (e)=>{
            console.log('error2' , e );
        });

})
```

you need some double checking  to avoide calling/adding duplicate streams/peers

here is my code check it out and see how i've done it

https://chate-test-3000.herokuapp.com/peer?room=someRomeName

just a heads up

```
var peer = new Peer({
    config: {'iceServers':  clientICE.iceServers } /* Sample servers, please use appropriate ones */
});
```

instead of `clientICE.iceServers` which i have used some commercial turn server

you have to provide your own iceservers and replace them here

you can use free google service

```
var peer = new Peer({
    config: {'iceServers': [
            { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        ]} /* Sample servers, please use appropriate ones */
});
```

eventually u need to use a commercial turn server to handle more complected network configs but for now google stun server works fine if your peers are in the same area

Comment: It is perfectly working on web to web. But why is not working on mobile ?

Comment: @FelixChristo you can try to see if you have any js errors on browser console (you can search to see how to do that in mobile browser ) ... bu i think webrtc is not supported on old ios devices so it might be that